# Send LINQ result to another function in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am developing a controller in which I consult information and the results are shown in the view of my controller and I send them via email by pressing a  "Send Email" button.

Here is an example:

[image: Example]

But when I want to pass my LINQ results to the `SendEmail()` method, I get an error.

The LINQ results are:

[Issue when i press Send Email button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihnNr.png)

Here is my controller

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcInventory.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Entities db = new Entities();
            var s = from sw in db.TB_RS_PROD.Where(x => x.IDPROD == 1)
                    select sw;
            ViewData["email"] = s;
            return View(s);
        }

        protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }

        public ActionResult SendEmail()
        {
            var htmlp = RenderPartialViewToString("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", ViewData["email"]);
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("IT@serv.com", "");
            SmtpServer.Port = 25;
            SmtpServer.Host = "150.147.12.155";
            mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("IT@serv.com", "IT TEAM");
            mail.To.Add("sz@serv.com");
            mail.Subject = "Request";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = htmlp;
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            return View("~/Views/Home/About.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

My view

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcInventory.TB_RS_PROD>
@{
}
<html>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>ID PRODUCT</td>
        <td>PRODUCT NAME</td>
        <td>QUIANTITY</td>
        <td>DATE</td>
        <td>STATUS</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td>@item.IDPROD</td>
           <td>@item.PROD_NAME</td>
           <td>@item.QUANTITY</td>
           <td>@item.UPDATE_DATE</td>
           <td>@item.STATUS</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SendEmail","Home")'">Send Email</button>
    </html>
```

I wanted to do it through `ViewData["email"]` since I understand that this way the values ​​can be passed.

Even so, I don't know how to solve this problem. It works if i put a static value but i need to put the LINQ result.

What should I do so that when I click the button I can send the email?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi you can use TempData["email"] = s; in your Index also use TempData.keep("email") after and in your sendEmail method get this TempData["email"].

Comment: "A simple change can be a big difference" Thank you so much @Ricky for resolve my issue , just I change ViewData for TempData!!